# End previous Proccess when a new one is called using NppExec

Tags: notepad++, nppexec

The message comes up saying would you like to send the exit command so you can run you new proccess.  well yes I would but I would like to always do this.

There has to be a way to add this in line to my script I just cant seem to find it.  Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear, but from what I understand, clicking on the console window and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> should end the previous process, after which you can use the run shortcut you configured to restart the process.

Notepad++ developers say [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/482781/topic/3235028) that they will not implement a command like NPP_TERMINATE to kill the console child process so looks like there's no way to write an NppExec script to do what <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does automatically.